# Operator <> issue

Tags: perl

I create a file named `fred`:

```
fred_1
fred_2
fred_3
```

I write a Perl script named `lac.pl`:

```
while(<>){
    print reverse <>;
}
```

Then I execute the below command.

[image]

Why did the output miss `fred_1`, and the program not end, just waiting for my  input?

If I update the Perl script like below, the result will be right:

```
print reverse <>;
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `while`, the `<>` will do all the reading for you. `print reverse <>;` is enough.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss the first line, because that was read into `$_` with your `while(<>)`.

```
  print reverse <>;
```

The `<>` is evaluated in list context. That is, all the remaining input is slurped into a list which is reversed and printed.

Now, the loop goes back to the conditional, waiting for another line on input. Try

```
print reverse <>;
```

by itself, not in a loop.

Of course, slurping like this will make the memory footprint of your program proportional to the size of its input which is not practical for large inputs.

If you do need to reverse large files, use [File::ReadBackwards](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::ReadBackwards;

for my $arg (@ARGV) {
    my $reader = File::ReadBackwards->new($arg)
        or die "Cannot read '$arg': $!";
    while (defined(my $line = $reader->readline)) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be kind of tricky to write an application to reverse a file line by line in constant memory. One implementation I remember created a source and destination memory mapped file, and used `memcpy` to write the first line to the end of the destination file, etc. You can also use a memory map to start reading at the end of the source and keep searching backward for new-line characters while creating output.

Comment: @ZanLynx Use `File::ReadBackwards`.

Answer (score 4):

Why was it wrong? Because `while(<>)` reads a line into `$_`. And then you ignore the value. Then it waits for your input because you used `<>` *again*, after it had finished. So it guesses you want to read from input, because you've used up everything else available.